# Python multiprocessing: how to safely change working directory of one of the processes

Tags: python, directory, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I need to run several parallel processes, each executing a set of functions. Like this:

```
import multiprocessing as mp  

data = [set1, set2, set3]  
functions = [func1, func2, func3, func4]  
# each func is run in its own separate directory

def myProcess(dataset, functions_list):  
    for func in functions_list:  
        func(dataset)  

for set_i in data:  
    p = mp.Process(target = myProcess, args = (set_i, functions))  
    p.start()
```

The problem is that each function in the `functions` list needs to be run in its separate directory. And `os.chdir` switches the directory for all processes being run, as far as I know. How can I ensure that each process safely runs in an appropriate directory without suddenly being kicked out of it by another one?

Comment: because of where it is dumping output or reading input? is that the reason it has to be in a different directory

Comment: the reason is that each function runs its corresponding external program, all of which are located in separate directories and use relative paths. so each program needs to be run in its own directory, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: "And  os.chdir switches the directory for all processes being run" - what makes you think that?

Comment: "use relative paths" isn't a reason to need to `chdir`. You can just manually resolve the paths relative to different directories.

Answer (score 1):

You're starting from an incorrect premise:

> And `os.chdir` switches the directory for all processes being run, as far as I know.

Nope. It switches the directory for the current process, not every process on the system (or even every process in the group, or anything like that).

Of course if you `chdir` in the parent before starting the children, the children will start in that new directory. But if you `chdir` in any of the children, it won't affect anyone else. And if you `chdir` in the parent after starting the children, it also won't affect anyone else.

---

> How can I ensure that each process safely runs in an appropriate directory without suddenly being kicked out of it by another one?

You don't have to do anything; that's how every operating system already works.

---

If you want to verify this for yourself, try running this program. On whatever platform you want, with every `startmethod` supported by that platform, you will see that the children can change directories independently, without affecting each other or the parent.

```
import multiprocessing
import os

def func():
    pid = str(os.getpid())
    print(f'{pid}: {os.getcwd()}')
    try:
        os.mkdir(pid)
    except FileExistsError:
        pass
    os.chdir(pid)
    print(f'{pid}: {os.getcwd()}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    startmethod = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv)>1 else 'fork'
    multiprocessing.set_start_method(startmethod)
    print(f'{os.getpid()}: {os.getcwd()}')
    children = [multiprocessing.Process(target=func) for _ in range(2)]
    for child in children:
        child.start()
    for child in children:
        child.join()
    print(f'{os.getpid()}: {os.getcwd()}')
```

Answer (score 1):

> In fact each process will be independent of each others and running
>   os.chdir in each of them will be done only for the process running it.

If you take a structure with three folder a, b, c.

This code will, for each folder, create a process which is going to create a file inside.

Each process waits 5 seconds before to create the file. So if the os.chdir was changing the directory for all processes, they would all create the file in the same directory. You will see that it is not the case and a file is created for each directory.

> Therefore os.chdir is not changing the directory for all the processes
>   if it is executed in the function run by a process.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
import os


def write_hello_world(directory):
    """Open a file with the same name as the directory in the directory

    In folder a we will create a file named a.

    :param str directory: directory where the file will be created.
    """
    os.chdir(directory)
    # We wait 5 seconds, all processes should have been started and changed directory.
    time.sleep(5)
    with open(directory, "w+") as f:
        # We write in the file the value of the directory
        f.write(directory)


# List of the process to join them in the end.
list_processes = []

# for each folder we create a process and we start it.
for directory in ["a", "b", "c"]:
    p = Process(target=write_hello_world, args=(directory,))
    p.start()

# Join the processes.
for process in list_processes:
    process.join()
```

Have a lovely day.